# How to position divs next to each other in a mail body?

Tags: css, html-email

I have spent hours trying to create an email template that acutally works. I am trying to position DIVs next to each other in the BODY of an confirmation email, that is to be sent from my website. So in the resulting email I have this :

```
      <div class="view-content" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <h3 style="margin: 0px;font-size: 14px;background-color: #eff1f7;border-top: 1px solid #dedede;border-left: 1px solid #dedede;border-right: 1px solid #dedede;padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;">TESTO 925 - temperaturmätare, typ K, radio, larm,</h3>
  <div class="views-responsive-grid views-responsive-grid-horizontal views-columns-3 checkout">
      <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-first" style="background-color: #eff1f7;border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;border-left: 1px solid #dedede;border-right: 1px solid #dedede;margin: 0px;">
      <div class="views-column views-column-1 views-column-first" style="color: #000;">

      <div class="views-field views-field-line-item-label" style="float: left;">    <span class="views-label views-label-line-item-label" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 13px;">Artikelnr: </span>    <div class="field-content artikelnr">0560 9250</div>  </div>  
      <div class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price" style="float: left;">    <span class="views-label views-label-commerce-unit-price" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 13px;">Pris: </span>    <div class="field-content price">995 kr</div>  </div>  
      <div class="views-field views-field-quantity" style="float: left;">    <span class="views-label views-label-quantity" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 13px;">Antal: </span>    <div class="field-content antal">1</div>  </div>  
      <div class="views-field views-field-commerce-total" style="float: left;">    <span class="views-label views-label-commerce-total" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 13px;">Summa: </span>    <div class="field-content price">995 kr</div>  </div>    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see I try to use `float:left` here, but I have also tried using `display:table` in the container (`.view-content`), and `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` respectively in the other DIVs. Other things I tried is using `display:block` and `display:inline-block`... with no luck. So what am I doing wrong here? Why do the DIVS with the class views-field above refuse to position themselves next to each other? There are reasons why I cannot use a simple table, a bit to lengthy to explain here.

UPD: OK, so I finally have to give this up and use a simple table approach because of lacking support for positioning of DIV's in popular email clients like Outlook 2013...

Comment: a fiddle or some bit of css code might help to understand more :)

Comment: With making HTML e-mail templates, you'll want to use tables rather than divs. See this tutorial: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770

Comment: Yes, I see that now, No support for div positioning in Outlook 2010/13 and so forth... I will have to rethink my approach. Thanks a lot anyway :-).

Comment: I had to create an email with styling not too long ago. It's a pain. Would an example be useful at all? Or do you got it?

Comment: Hi, have begun to create a simple styling using tables instead of divs, but it would be really useful to see an example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No option should be considered except for table tag when creating Mailers.Even SendGrid prefers to send mail which are coded using table tag.

I prefer to two create two DIVs with different or same width,resulting in a total of 600px. Then, apply **maxwidth** to keep both DIVs stackable on mobile devices.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
  <table style="max-width:600px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">
            <table style="text-align:left" align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width:100%;border:1px solid #dddddd" valign="top">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;border-bottom:3px solid #2e3192" valign="top">
                                    <table style="max-width:600px" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>
                                            <img src="http://images.sixrevisions.com/2009/02/03-09_3d_logo_tutorial.jpg" style="display:block;max-width:80%;margin-right:15px" align="left" border="0" class="CToWUd" width="150px" height="80px">
                                          </td>

                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;padding-top:9px;padding-bottom:9px" width="100%">
                                    <span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;padding-left:9px;font-family:arial">Dear</span>
                                    <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold">Amandeep,</span>

                                    <br>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="background:#f1f1f1;padding:7px">
                                          <table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14px" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td style="background:#ffffff;padding:10px">
                                                  <table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14px" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                          <h1 style="color:#4e4e4e;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;display:inline;padding-right:10px">Teddybear Soft Toy </h1>
                                                        </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="" rowspan="" headers="" style="border-bottom:1px solid #c4c4c4;padding-top:10px"></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                  <div style="display:inline-block;max-width:350px;width:100%;vertical-align:middle">
                                                    <table style="padding:5px;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td colspan="2">We Want To Buy Teddybear Soft Toy. Kindly share the quotation for the same.</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div style="display:inline-block;max-width:220px;width:100%;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">
                                                    <table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="center"><a style="padding:10px 20px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid #5e9122;background:#5e9122;background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#5e9122),to(#5e9122));background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#5e9122,#5e9122);color:#ffffff;border-radius:4px;font-size:17px;width:200px;display:table-cell;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" rel="external" href="#">Contact Buyer 
                                                            </a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                  </div>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td></tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can test your Mailer from this site [PUTSMAIL](https://putsmail.com/tests/new)
Works like a charm on all Mail clients.

Comment: Thanks for this example. Very useful!

Comment: PUTSMAIL is what I used to test it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go ahead and post my example as well. Sudhir Kaushik's example looks good.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    #outlook a{padding:0}body{width:100%!important;background-color:#333;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;margin:0!important;padding:0!important}.ReadMsgBody{width:100%}.ExternalClass{width:100%}ol li{margin-bottom:15px}img{height:auto;line-height:100%;outline:none;text-decoration:none}#backgroundTable{height:100%!important;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%!important}p{margin:1em 0}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{color:#222!important;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:100%!important}table td{border-collapse:collapse}.yshortcuts,.yshortcuts a,.yshortcuts a:link,.yshortcuts a:visited,.yshortcuts a:hover,.yshortcuts a span{color:#000;text-decoration:none!important;border-bottom:none!important;background:none!important}.im{color:#000}div[id='tablewrap']{width:100%;max-width:600px!important}table[class='fulltable'],td[class='fulltd']{max-width:100%!important;width:100%!important;height:auto!important}@media screen and (max-device-width: 430px),screen and (max-width: 430px){td[class=emailcolsplit]{width:100%!important;float:left!important;padding-left:0!important;max-width:430px!important}td[class=emailcolsplit] img{margin-bottom:20px!important}}
  </style>
</head>

<body style='width:100% !important; margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none; background-color:#FFFFFF;'>
  <table border='0' cellpadding='0' align='center' cellspacing='0' id='backgroundTable' style='height:auto !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; background-color:#333; color:#222222;'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id='tablewrap' align='center' style='width:100% !important; max-width:600px !important; text-align:center !important; margin-top:0 !important; margin-right: auto !important; margin-bottom:0 !important; margin-left: auto !important;'>
          <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' id='contenttable' style='background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center !important; margin-top:0 !important; margin-right: auto !important; margin-bottom:0 !important; margin-left: auto !important; border:none; width: 100% !important; max-width:600px !important;'
            width='600'>
            <tr>
              <td width='100%'>
                <table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' border='0' cellspacing='0' style='padding-right:25px' width='100%'>
                  <tr>
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='text-align:right;' width='100%'>
                      <a href='#'><img alt='Main banner image and link' border='0' src='http://placehold.it/72x100' style='display:inline-block; max-width:72px !important; width:100% !important; height:auto !important;'></a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' border='0' cellpadding='25' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                  <tr>
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='text-align:left;' width='100%'>
                      <p style='color:#222222; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height:19px; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:20px; padding:0; font-weight:normal;'>
                        Dear Customer,
                      </p>
                      <p style='color:#222222; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height:19px; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:20px;margin-left:20px; padding:0; font-weight:normal;'>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                      </p>
                      <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='emailwrapto100pc' width='100%'>
                        <tr>
                          <td align='right' class='emailcolsplit' valign='top' width='100%'>
                            <p style='color:#222222; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height:19px; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:20px; margin-left:20px; padding:0; font-weight:normal; text-align:left;'>
                              Please call us at 555-555-5555 with any questions.
                            </p>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align='left' class='emailcolsplit' valign='top' width='58%'>
                            <address style='font-size:15px; margin: 0; line-height: 1.25em; font-family: Helvetica, Arial'>
            <p>
            <span style='font-weight:600; font-size: 18px'>Your Company Inc</span><br>
            400 Tech Drive<br>
            Some City, State 22222<br>
            <abbr title='Phone'><strong>P:</strong></abbr>555.555.5555<br>
            <strong>Email:</strong><a href='mailto:hr@yourcompany.com'>hr@yourcompany.com</a>
            </p>
            </address>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

So beautiful right? This formatting drives me crazy. My email was a response to customers, but I'm sure it can be easily applied to other scenarios.
 Good Luck!

Comment: Good one, mine had some shorthand CSS but works fine except for box shadow and border radius in outlook and yahoo Old versions.

Comment: Great work! With these examples I feel confident to create something useful for the client. Thanks again!